# Need to synchronize a table with a query (view) in the same Sql Server Database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, synchronization, merge, recursive-query

I need to keep a table in sync with a recursive CTE query that joins to multiple tables.  The CTE may return different results every time it's ran (if any changes were made to the tables it joins on).  The CTE is slow and I can't afford to have a trigger run it since the query that caused the trigger to fire won't return until after the trigger has fired (I don't want a simple update to a single record to take 15 seconds because it's waiting on the trigger to finish).  Any details on how to implement the solution in SSMS would be nice too, but not necessary.

One solution would be to have a scheduled job run the CTE, and merge it's results with the table.  The scheduled job can run every few seconds so the table  is as up-to-date as possible.  But I don't know how to create a scheduled job in Sql Server 2005 or how to Merge the results of a CTE query with a table.

To restate my question:

*How do I keep the table up to date as close to real-time as possible using the CTE?*

Comment: Scheduled jobs can run once per minute at most not every few seconds. I suspect the answer may well involve a service broker queue. How critical is it if the table returns out-of-date data? i.e. should `selects` be blocked if the table is not yet synchronised?

Comment: No.  It's much better to keep the table selectable.  That is hard fast requirement.  As far as out of sync time... it's fine to be a minute or two out of sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself.  Using the Sql Server Agent, along with the very cool [tablediff.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162843%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) utility, I was able to keep the view and table in sync using the upsert/delete statements generated by the tablediff util.  It required a temp table and a unique column in the view (which I created by concatenating 2 column ids into one (which I knew would make it unique)).

This was a much better solution because I didn't have to truncate the live table or drop it and rename the temp table.  Plus it runs in it's own thread/environment so it's ok if it takes a minute to run (vs using a trigger which always needs to be fast).

If anyone wants more details let me know and I'll update this article.